# Android get single row from database based on listview id

Tags: android, database, listview, android-listview, cursor

```
//function which is in my DatabaseHelper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper
public String getCoordinatesLatitude(int id) {
    String rowLat = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String latQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_LATITUDE + "FROM " + TABLE_COORDINATES + "WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + id;
    Cursor cursorr = db.rawQuery(latQuery,null);
    if (cursorr != null){
        cursorr.moveToPosition(id);
        rowLat = cursorr.getString(cursorr.getColumnIndex(KEY_LATITUDE));
    }

    // return coordinates
    return rowLat;
}

//function in my main activity
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

      selectedFromList = (String) (l.getItemAtPosition(position));
      selectedItem = (int) l.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
      String rowLat = helper.getCoordinatesLatitude(selectedItem);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rowLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
```

I have a `listview` which contains `locations`. Each location contains `latitude`,`longitude` and a date. What i basically want is to click on a `listview` item, and retrieve the items `latitude` value from my database, based on its `listview` ID. I setup the `getCoordinatesLatitude()` function but i dont know if my code is correct, because when i click on a `listview` item i get force close and logcat shows `nullPointerException`. How can i make this work? Thanks

What my listview looks like
[image: what my listview looks like]

**UPDATE!!!!**
I managed to get rid of nullPointerException error, and changed my code to this

```
 public String getLatitudeFromId(long id) {
    String rowLat = "not found";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //String latQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_LATITUDE + " FROM " + TABLE_COORDINATES + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + id;
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(latQuery,null);
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COORDINATES, new String[] { "latitude" },"id="+id, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        cursor.moveToPosition((int) id);
        rowLat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return coordinates
    return rowLat;
}
```

and

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    selectedFromList = (String) (l.getItemAtPosition(position));
    selectedItem = l.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    String rowLat = helper.getLatitudeFromId(selectedItem);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rowLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But now, when i click on listview item, the toast is not found, so it stops in the if (cursor.moveToFirst()) statement because the cursor is empty. How can the cursor be empty when my listview is full of items? :P

**UPDATE2**
I fixed the problem just by changing my query to this Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COORDINATES, new String[] {KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null,null); where KEY_DATE is the column name that you want to be shown when u click an item in the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually worked my way out. Strangely though, i changed my query to this 
     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COORDINATES, new String[] {KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null,null); 
just letting the selection to null and only having the column that i wanted, and it worked! This question can be marked as answered.

Comment: That query return all rows in database. Seems to work only if first list item is selected or all rows are equal, what seems to be the case

Comment: I know, thats weird isnt it? I tested it with different coordinates and it works like a charm

Comment: Now works because cursor.moveToPosition, but after you delete some rows and add others stops working.

Answer (score 1):

If the array which you have assigned to listview adapter is "array" then you can retrieve array.get(position).getLatitude(); (I assume you have use custom adapter)

Comment: what i want is click on listview, store its position to selectedItem, then pass selectedItem to my getCoordinatesLatitude(selectedItem); and then the function will search my database and return me the latitude which id is equal to selectedItem, but i dont know if my function is correct

Comment: I haven't used a custom adapter, but thats not the point. I want a function that will scan my database and return me the latitude from the row that has the same id as my selectedItem

Answer (score 0):

First your table must have a column set as primary key named _id not id. Then you can pass to getLatitudeFromId the id you get from onItemClick.

Change getLatitudeFromId(long id) to this:

```
 public String getLatitudeFromId(long id) {
    String rowLat = "not found";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COORDINATES, new String[] { "latitude" },"_id=" + id, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        rowLat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return coordinates
    return rowLat;
}
```

Change onListItemClick to this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   // ??? selectedFromList = (String) (l.getItemAtPosition(position));
   // ??? selectedItem = l.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    String rowLat = helper.getLatitudeFromId(id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rowLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Note: l.getItemAtPosition(position) returns a view not string neither int